# how to declare dynamique variable names ionic 2

Tags: list, angular, variables, typescript, ionic2

im wondering how to dynamicaly declare variable name with ionic 2.
i want to implemet a read more function with ion-list result but to do it i need to have individual variable names.

// my ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController,Platform ,LoadingController, NavParams } from 'ionic-
angular';
import { GardeService } from '../../app/services/Garde.service';



@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})


export class Home {
//data:any;
public newslist: Array<Object>;
mytext:any;
prewords:any;
textpreview:any;
fulltext:any;



constructor(public data:GardeService) {}

ngOnInit()
{
    this.loadnews();
    this.fulltext = true;
    this.textpreview = false;
}

  public loadnews(){
  this.newslist = [];
  var map: {[key:string]:string} = {};
  this.data.LoadNews().subscribe(
  data => {
  for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        //this.newslist.push(data[i]);
        //console.log("news",data[i].content);
        this.mytext = data[i].content.split(' ');
        this.prewords = this.mytext[0] + " " + this.mytext[1] + " " +           
   this.mytext[2] + " " + this.mytext[3] + " " +
        this.mytext[4] + " " + this.mytext[5] + " " + this.mytext[6] + " " + 
   this.mytext[7] + " " + this.mytext[8] + " " +
        this.mytext[9] + " " + this.mytext[10] + " " + this.mytext[11] + " " 
   + this.mytext[12] + " " + this.mytext[13] + " " +
        this.mytext[14] + " " + this.mytext[15] + " " + this.mytext[16] + "" 
       + this.mytext[17] + " " + this.mytext[18] + " " +
        this.mytext[19] + " " + this.mytext[20];
        //map['fulltext'+i] = true;
        this.textpreview = false;
        this.newslist.push({poster: data[i].poster, title: data[i].title, 
       img:data[i].img, content:data[i].content,
        pre:this.prewords});

        //console.log("les mots descriptifs",this.prewords);
  }
},
err => {
  console.log(err);
},
() => console.log('news loaded')
);
}

public readMore(){
  this.textpreview = true;
  this.fulltext = false;
}
}


// my html file

    ion-col width-100 text-wrap>
        <p style="text-align:justify;" color="dark" ion-text>
          <span ion-text [hidden]="textpreview">{{item.pre}}</span><span 
    ion-text (click)="readMore()">...Lire plus</span>
      <span ion-text [hidden]="fulltext">{{item.content}}</span>
    </p>
  </ion-col>
```

i want to have dynamic changing this.fulltext and this.textpreview variable names in order to do that because when i click the read more link all the content of all the ion-itens extend . i only want it to happen the place i click

Comment: Can you save the results in an array? How is a new? How do you know it has more text to be loaded?
It seems to me that a *ngFor with an accordion could do the trick for you.

Comment: yes the result is saved in an array, let me show you the full code

Comment: with an accordion can you give me an example? or a s way to implement a read more funvtion on a long text

Comment: You should create a custom component for each _new_ (item of the list). That way each component will need to handle its own properties, and it won't depend on the amount of instances of the same component in the page.

Comment: can you give me an example? of the component